# Getting no tty present and no askpass program specified when using git over ssh

Tags: ssh, sudo, git, tty

I'm trying to push a `git commit` from my laptop to my server but keep getting the following error message:

```
remote: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified 
To ssh://git@example.com/~/site_hub
```

I have the following in my sudoers:

```
Defaults:git !requiretty
git ALL=(apache) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git
```

Not sure why I'm getting that error message. I've Googled around but I'm not finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

ssh does not always open a (pseudo) tty. This may be the case here. tty allocation can be enforced though: `ssh -t` or even `ssh -tt`. If you cannot pass command line arguments then you can do the same via the config file: `RequestTTY yes` or `RequestTTY force`, see man ssh_config.

Comment: The ssh is through a Win Vista laptop git pgm (msysGit) to a CentOS server. Guess I'll have to see if I can make those changes on the Win end.